# Auto populate qgis file name with no file extension?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-2, expression

I'm looking to be able to auto populate an attribute field with the project file name either by a virtual field or default option in the properties. The "@project_filename" expression always produces a result with the file extension. eg "newproject.qgs" I don't want the ".qgs" displayed.

Comment: just trim the last four character....

Comment: If you use QGIS 3, there is the `@project_basename` which just returns the name without path or extension.

Comment: Sadly at the moment I have to use 2.14 or 2.18. (office politics) The field has to populate a large number of entries automatically so manually removing the extension isn't an option.

Answer (score 6):

You could replace `'.qgs'` by nothing `''` in your expression:

```
replace( @project_filename , '.qgs', '')
```

As J.R pointed out, you could also select the whole filename, minus the last 4 characters

```
substr( @project_filename ,1,-4)
```

Comment: replace( @project_filename , '.qgs', '')  That does the trick thanks.